# Changing graph on radio button selection change - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonlist, microsoft-chart-controls

I use Microsoft chart and I have below line of code to get chart.

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("GetChart")" alt="Bar Chart using MVC" class="img-responsive" />
```

I have a radio button list and upon changing the selection, i need to show a different chart in the same place.

```
<form method="post" id="frmFormType">
        @Html.Label("Select Chart Type")
        @Html.RadioButton("rbChartType", "1", isChecked: true) @Html.Label("First Option")
        @Html.RadioButton("rbChartType", "2", isChecked: false) @Html.Label("Second option")
    </form>
```

I'm not sure if I can use jQuery change function on this "rbChartType" or use something take advantage of Form.  I don't really need to re-post the page but only to change graph.  I am not sure how to refetch new chart when selection changed using jQuery.  Can anyone please throw some light on this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have both the images:

[image]

[image]

Make them this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").click(function () {
    $(".graph").addClass("hidden");
    $("#" + $(this).attr("value")).removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
img {display: block;}
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="graph" value="graph-1" /> Graph 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="graph" value="graph-2" /> Graph 2</label>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=50&txt=Graph%201&w=200&h=200" class="graph hidden" id="graph-1" />
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=50&txt=Graph%202&w=200&h=200" class="graph hidden" id="graph-2" />
```

Comment: this solution requires all graphs to be loaded at the time of page load, which is not an elegant solution. Page size increases a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can try it!

```
$(function(){
   $(":radio").click(function() { 
       //do something 
    }); 
})
```

if above soluation did not work,please use the debug of browser to look for the correct documents.
in this way ,you can operate documents with jquery.

---

First,you have to get the srcs of each RadioButton ,if you want to change the img of src by click radio. 
$(function(){
     $("input:radio").click(function(){
      if($(this).is("#1")){$(".img").css('background',src1);}else{$(".img").css('background',src2);}})

Comment: well, i have started off this but I don't know how to rebind img src tag. Do you have an example?